# Save trained NetChain between Mathematica sessions?

Tags: export, machine-learning, neural-networks, persistence

Let's say I have written a `NetChain` machine learning setup, trained the chain with `NetTrain` and obtained a model ready to predict:

```
model = NetChain[...];
trained = NetTrain[model,...];
```

The whole process took a long time to prepare, so I do not want to repeat the same preparation steps the next time I start Mathematica. Is there a way to save `trained` and load from memory instead of recreating it?

Comment: Pretty sure you can just save it via the normal routes, e.g. .m, .mx, compressed string, byte array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>"mynet.wlnet",trained]

Just use Import on the same file to reload into memory.